# Get the same result as the "by" function but to a vector

Tags: r

I'm currently working with the diamonds dataset in de ggplot package.

I would like to get the “cut” field with the highest median “price” value. I can get the result using the by function.

```
by(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, median)
```

I what to get only the name of the “cut” with the highest median “price”. I’m trying to pass the “by” values to a matrix, so I can get the column that I need, but without success so far.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `names` not working? `names(by(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, median))`

Comment: yes, but lack the filtering part of the value. the `Tapply` turns out to be a more flexible solution, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by()` is one member of a family of base R functions that split data by a classifying factor, perform summarizing computations on the splits, and return the results in a variety of different formats. Others include `aggregate()`, `ave()`, and `tapply()`, the latter of which is what I'd use here:

```
meds <- tapply(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, median)
names(which.max(meds))
# [1] "Fair"
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `by` also works in this case: `names(which.max(by(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, median)))`

Comment: @thelatemail -- Yeah, I saw that too, and was mildly surprised. tapply() still feels more straightforward here, but probably just because I happen to use it more often ;)